# Is there any way that I can include a variable in range?

Tags: variables, range, multiplication

```
number = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
multiply = int(input("What would you like me to multiply it up to: "))

for count in range (1,int(mutliply)):
    product = number *count
    print(number, "x", count,"=", product)
```

Very time I try, an error occurs saying that:
*'for count in range (1,int(mulitply)):
NameError: name 'mulitply' is not defined'
How do I fix this? :)

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelled the variable multiply.

Also you've already casted the multiply into an int type so you don't need to repeat that.

This code will work now.

```
number = int(input("Enter an integer: ")) 

multiply = int(input("What would you like me to multiply it up to: ")) 

for count in range (1,multiply):
    product = number *count
    print(number, "x", count,"=", product)
```